# How to chain promises right in js?

Tags: javascript

I have a code below:

```
.then(function () {
    /*first block*/ 
    service.firstMethod()
})
.then(function () {
    /*second block*/
    some logic;
})

service.firstMethod = function () {
    some plain code;

        otherService.serverCall(arguments)
            .then(function (result) {
          processing result;
            })
            .then(function (result)
                processing result;
            })
            .then(function (result) {
                processing result;
            })
            .then(function (result) {
                processing result;

            });
    });
};
```

When firstMethod() is called from first block - it is running some plain code and then goes to second block and only after second block finished executing its call to server and so on. How to make the whole firstMethod be executed before execution of second block will be started? It is quite old project no async/await available.

Comment: You'll need to `return otherService.serverCall()` from the `firstMethod` and handle the  `then` outside.

Comment: Also RETURN for service.firstMethod(); call is required in first block.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```js
var service = {};

service.subMethod = new Promise(function (resolve) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    // waiting 3 seconds
    console.log('subMethod done...');
    resolve();
  }, 3000);
});

service.firstMethod = new Promise(function (resolve) {
  service.subMethod.then(function () {
    console.log('firstMethod done...');
    
    resolve();
  });
});

service.secondMethod = new Promise(function (resolve) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    // waiting 5 seconds
    console.log('secondMethod done...');
    resolve();
  }, 5000);
});

var main = new Promise(function (resolve) {
  service.firstMethod.then(service.secondMethod);
});
```

In the beginning, we start `firstMethod`, inside this method, we call `subMethod`. When `subMethod`'s done, we've done `firstMethod` and continue with `secondMethod`

**Note:** You can also use callback to do that.